# Azure Blob Custom Role

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, rbac

I have created a  custom role from a JSON file and the role name is "Storage Blob Operations_Custom"
The purpose of this role is i would like to give my Azure Admin all the Data Actions except seeing the Blob Contents in the respective containers.
My role definition is given below

```
{
    "name": "Storage Blob Operations_Custom",
    "IsCustom": true,
    "Description": "Return a container or list of containers + Perform Data Actions on a blob except reading the blob contents",
    "Actions": [
              "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/read"
    ],
    "NotActions": [
              "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/delete",
              "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/write",
              "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/generateUserDelegationKey/action"
  ],
    "DataActions": [
            "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/delete",
            "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/write",
            "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/move/action",
            "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/add/action"
  ],
    "NotDataActions": [],
    "AssignableScopes": [
            "/subscriptions/<my subscription ID>"
    ]
  }
```

After assigning this role to a particular user, when i log in with that user account, i am not able to upload any blobs to the containers that i have, i am not able to view the blobs also if i click on any of the containers
Even though my data actions has blobs/delete and blobs/write, why i am not able to view the blobs or upload any blobs?
How do i ensure that i can see the blob (Excluding the contents) and perform operations on the blobs, like delete, upload, move and add.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> How do i ensure that i can see the blob (Excluding the contents) and
> perform operations on the blobs, like delete, upload, move and add.

Unfortunately you can't. The reason being there's only one data action (`Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/read`) which is used for both listing the blobs and reading contents of a blob. There's no data action just for listing the blobs.

[image]

One thing you could do is include this permission and then make use of `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` with just `List` permission in your application.